# Understanding javax.el.ValueExpression purpose

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I'm trying to understand the working principles of `UIInput` component and EL-expressions in JSF. Here is the code fragment of `UIInput` component source code:

```
public void updateModel(FacesContext context) {

        if (context == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if (!isValid() || !isLocalValueSet()) {
            return;
        }
        ValueExpression ve = getValueExpression("value");
        if (ve != null) {
            Throwable caught = null;
            FacesMessage message = null;
            try {
                ve.setValue(context.getELContext(), getLocalValue()); //1
                setValue(null);
                setLocalValueSet(false);
            }
            //catch clause
```

Now, I have a simple bean and the input component binded to its property:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.hello}" />
```

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean{
    private String hello;
    //getter,setter
}
```

As far as I understand, the `updateModel` method is called by the inherited from the `UIComponentBase` class `processUpdates(FacesContext)` method which is a standard callback for the `Update Model Values` phase. So, after setting breakpoint at `//1` and performing step next the flow's stopped at the corresponding bean property setter method.

My question is about of purpose of `javax.el.ValueExpression`. Is it resposible for all interatctions (incapsulates) between the component class and the bean's property in order for getting/setting values to bean's properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EL is like a "path" and is needed to navigate the bean. The UIInput is the MVC "view" to the MVC "model" represented by your bean. EL links the two together. It only encapsulates the traversal itself. It identifies the subject of the interaction, but the interactions are defined by the component class. Compare `h:outputText` to `h:inputText`: both basically take a `value="#{some.el}"` attribute; the fact that one allows the user to modify it is a fact about the component, not the path to the bean property itself.

Some components define attributes that should be populated by references to methods rather than bean properties, but again, the EL is just the traversal—invoking those methods is something the component does. And in that case you would be dealing with a `MethodExpression` instead of a `ValueExpression`.

The JSF lifecycle dictates that things happen in a certain overall order, but the component author still has ample opportunity to be creative (or wreak havoc) by doing things their own way.

Comment: So why does setting the bean property always happen when I call `ValueExpression.setValue(ELContext, Object);`

Comment: That seems like 90% of the point of it to me… why is it surprising or confusing to you? The whole JSF concept would be really limited if it didn't allow the user to edit values.

Comment: No, I asked about if the Value Expressions were designed specifically for interacting with beans' properties through them?

Comment: EL is designed to make it easy to provide a path through a JavaBean object graph, the final destination usually being a value, but it can also be a non-JavaBean method. ValueExpressions, as you know, make it possible to replace the value at that location with another value—which is essential functionality for almost any UIInput. If this doesn't answer your question you will need to restate it.

Comment: One little clarification: Can we say that Value Expressions represent the value access  in a JavaBean style (i.e. getValue(), setValue())?